# Can partially observable MDPs be fully observable nonetheless?

Tags: terminology

I've read through a few definitions of a partially observable environment/MDP, and I need confirmation whether the *partial observability* is really a *generalization* of a MDP (misnomer) and not a *required* feature, just like when we call nondeterministic automata the union of a) deterministic automata and b) (what I like to call) the actually nondeterministic automata.

The question can be satisfied simply by answering: Is tic-tac-toe partially observable?

Answer (score 1):

Every MDP can be transformed into a POMDP (partially observable MDP), such that the signal (observation) is the state itself. There is no benefit in doing so, but it is still a valid transformation.

In this sense, Tic-Tac-Toe is fully observable (you see the entire state you are in, and not a partial signal from it), and hence can be transformed into a partially observable MDP.

Comment: So what you're saying is that Tic-Tac-Toe is **not** a partially observable MDP, but it has to be *transformed* into a partially observable MDP?

Comment: Or what you're saying is that Tic-Tac-Toe is not a MDP, it's the name of a game, and the game is not distinguishably fully observable nor partially observable, because those terms are not defined for games, only for MDPs, and if you wan't to talk about observability and TTT in the same context, you somehow need to transform TTT into some MDP before you can analyse its observability?

Comment: By Tic-Tac-Toe I meant the MDP representing that game. And yea, you got me right: you can create an MDP for the Tic-Tac-Toe game that is **not** partially observable, but you can *transform* it to a partially observable MDP. Again, there is absolutely no benefit in doing so, and it will just complicate everything. The algorithms for POMDPs are much worse than those for MDPs, so stick with it being an MDP unless you absolutely must treat it as a POMDP

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One more question before I upvote and accept: When you think of a game and discuss whether the game is partially observable or fully observable, would you argue that a game is fully observable iff you can create *both* MDP and POMDP for it, and that a game is partially observable iff you can only create a POMDP for it, but not a classic MDP?

Comment: Speaking realistically, when someone says they have a POMDP for some game, you shouldn't make any assumption about there existing an MDP. There might be a small MDP, but also it could be one with a state space that is too large (for example, one with an infinite state space). Or maybe, it could even be that there isn't one at all that can represent what you are trying to accomplish in the game. For example, if you are trying to play a card game, you don't want to know at every moment in time what cards your opponent holds, since it would totally ruin the game.